# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b \sin x \arctan(nx) dx$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification

> Compute $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b \sin x \arctan(nx) dx$$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$.

Let $I_n= \int_a^b \sin x \arctan(nx) dx$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
By IBP we have that 
$$
\begin{split}
I_n &= \int_a^b(-\cos x)'\arctan(nx)dx \\
    &= -\cos b \arctan(nb)+\cos a \arctan(na)+\int_a^b \cos x\frac{n}{1+(nx)^2}dx
\end{split}
$$
By applying the MVT for integrals we have that $\exists c_n \in (a,b)$ such that $$\int_a^b \cos x \cdot \frac{n}{1+(nx)^2}dx=\cos c_n \int_a^b \frac{n}{1+(nx)^2}dx=\cos c_n(\arctan(nb)-\arctan(na)).$$
As a result, $I_n=\arctan(na)(\cos a-\cos c_n)+\arctan(nb)(\cos c_n-\cos b)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Since the arctangent is increasing and $a<b$, we have that $\arctan(na)<\arctan (nb)$.
We get that $$\arctan(na)(\cos a-\cos b) < I_n < \arctan(nb)(\cos a-\cos b), \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
If $a>0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} I_n=\frac{\pi}{2}(\cos a- \cos b)$.
We are left with the case $a\le 0$. I would like to know if the solution I presented for $a>0$ is correct. If it is, I will try to find a way to also deal with $a \le 0$.
EDIT: Thanks to an idea from an user in the comments the approach I presented can be extended to the remaining cases. A good observation is that this limit becomes significantly easier if we use the Dominated Convergence Theorem (honestly, I didn't even think about it because I got this problem from a magazine for high school students and they don't learn this theorem, but nevertheless the DCT is the most efficient way here).

Comment: The case when $a < 0$ is incorrect. When $a = -b$ you are claiming the integral is always 0, but $\sin(x) \tan^{-1}(nx)$ is non-negative for $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @WillieWong ah, you are correct, thank you ! This error stems from the fact that I assumed that $b$ would also be a negative number (if $b$ is positive and $a$ is negative I can no longer use the squeeze theorem). I will edit my post.

Comment: For negative $a$ and positive $b$, split the integral at $0$ and in the integral with lower limit $a$, perform the change of integration varaible $x \to -x$. If both are negative, perform the change of integration varaible $x \to -x$. After that, you may use what you have proved already.

Comment: @Gary Thank you ! This solves the problem in a nice and elementary way (even though it gets pretty lengthy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_0^b \sin(x)\arctan(nx)\,dx=\frac\pi2\,\text{sgn}(b)\,(1-\cos(b))$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\int_a^0 \sin(x)\arctan(nx)\,dx=-\frac\pi2\,\text{sgn}(a)(1-\cos(a))$$

Putting it together we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b \sin(x)\arctan(nx)\,dx= \frac\pi2\,\text{sgn}(b)\,(1-\cos(b))-\frac\pi2\,\text{sgn}(a)\,(1-\cos(a))$$

Comment: Thanks ! I think that we may use the DCT in all cases, right?

Comment: Yes, the DCT applies to all cases.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

The antiderivative
$$I=\int \frac{n\cos (x)}{1+(nx)^2}dx$$ is interesting. Using partial fraction decomposition, write it as
$$I=\frac {i }2 \left(\int \frac{n\cos (x)}{n x+i}\,dx- \int \frac{n\cos (x)}{n x-i}\,dx\right)$$ and
$$\int \frac{n\cos (x)}{n x+k}\,dx=\cos \left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \text{Ci}\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \text{Si}\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)$$